# Extraer información de un elemento activo por XPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de webscrapping y estoy tratando de extraer el numero de teléfono  "8180637258 / 8181638708" de el elemento activo, estoy consciente de que primero se tiene que llamar el metodo `driver. switch_to_active_element()`  para poder hacer uso del HTML del elemento, pero al momento de llamarlo por XPath, me aparece un error diciendo que no existe ese elemento

Intenté por otro tipo de método `find_element` pero tampoco me arroja resultado. Y ya intenté buscar otros tags por su `XPath` (como por ejemplo el que viene arriba del seleccionado) y no me muestran error pero no me muestra su información, solo un código que arroja Selenium Webdriver

Ya leí la documentación de Selenium e investigué  varias paginas y vídeos pero no logro extraer el número teléfono.

Este es el código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Firefox()       #Se declara el navegador con el que se va a estar trabajando


driver.set_page_load_timeout(10000)   #Delay para carga la pagina

driver.get("http://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/bodega-en-venta-zona-industrial-monterrey-nuevo-leon.-51774657.html") #Se almacena el url 
#driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation step by step")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-phone").click()    #Se busca el boton "Ver telefono"  para desplegar el numero del contacto aplicando un filtro por selectores de CSS
#driver. switch_to_active_element()  #webdriver se pasa a la pantalla de infromacion del contacto 
numero = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div/a[2]") #se extrae el numero del contacto a traves de XPath
print(numero.text)


url = requests.get("http://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/nave-industrial-en-venta-en-guadalupe-53310791.html") #se utiliza la lib "request" para almancenar el url
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html5lib") 
nombre_contacto = soup.find_all("span", {"class", "h3"}) #incia la busqueda en las estiquetas span donde se encuentra el nombre del contacto


for nombre in nombre_contacto:
    print(nombre.text)         #Se inicia el ciclo para que se despliegue todos los resultado en forma de texto
```

Y este el error que obtengo:

```
    ============ RESTART: C:\Users\diego\Desktop\Selenium pruebas.py ============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\diego\Desktop\Selenium pruebas.py", line 18, in <module>
    numero = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div/a[2]") #se extrae el numero del contacto a traves de XPath
  File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 368, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 858, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div/a[2]
```

Comment: Hola Diego, agrega el código y el error como texto siempre. Las imágenes dificultan la reproducción del código, no permiten indexar el contenido para futuras búsquedas y dificultan la legibilidad, en dispositivos móviles por ejemplo. Añade  tu código como como texto formateandolo adecuadamente, para ello lo pegas, los seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor.

Comment: Claro, dame un segundo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El número de teléfono no aparece de inmediato. Se hace una llamada ajax que modifica el contenido del DOM. Tienes que poner alguna clase de espera entre presionar el botón y buscar el número.

Por ejemplo:

```
driver.get("http://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/bodega-en-venta-zona-industrial-monterrey-nuevo-leon.-51774657.html")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-phone").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # espera 10 segundos por si el elemento aún no existe
numero = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div/a[2]")
print(numero.text)
```

Aunque también puedes hacer que el thread espere 10 segundos

```
import time 

driver.get("http://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/bodega-en-venta-zona-industrial-monterrey-nuevo-leon.-51774657.html")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-phone").click()
time.sleep(10) # pones el thread en pausa por 10 segundos
numero = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div/a[2]")
print(numero.text)
```

En todo caso, según yo los XPath del número son

```
//*[@id="id-verdatos-aviso-1"]/div/a[3]
```

y

```
//*[@id="ficha"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span
```

Comment: **Le agregue el timer pero me despliega  un error de "legal expression"**


File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//[@id='verdatos-aviso-1']/div/a[3]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Ese error no te lo da por la espera sino por la sintaxis del selector xpath. Prueba en la consola de Chrome si luego de pinchar el botón te encuentra algo con `$x("//*[@id='id-verdatos-aviso-1']/div/a[3]")`. Recuerda que luego del doble slash viene un asterisco

Comment: Ya pude correr el codigo y desplegar el  numero, muchas gracias!!
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#driver. switch_to_active_element()  #webdriver se pasa a la pantalla de infromacion del contacto 
#numero = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div/a[1]") #se extrae el numero del contacto a traves de XPath
numero = driver.find_element_by_class_name("phone")
print(numero.text)

Con este codigo corrio